# Create confirm message based on form value filled out or not

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im trying to create a confirm() message to pop-up once the Run Script button is pressed, but i wish to display different messages if one of the form fields is filled in or not.

This is the code i'm using now on the form, and it works, but not sure how to add more IF's statements to it so it changes depending if Form1.projectid.value is filled in, and another message if it is not filled in. Is it possible?

Working code:

```
 <form method="post" id="Form1" name="Form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="" />
    <table style="table-layout: fixed; overflow: hidden; padding: 1px; border: none;">
        <tr>
            <td>Cut-Off Period:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="cutoff" class="TdInput" style="width: 180px">
                    <option value="<%=sPrevPrev%>"><%=sPrevPrev%></option>
                    <option value="<%=sPrev%>" selected><%=sPrev%> (Normally this!)</option>
                    <option value="<%=sThis%>"><%=sThis%></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td nowrap>BA selection: &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                <select name="batype" id="demo" class="TdInput" style="width: 180px" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <option value="" <%if sBaType = "" then response.write(" selected ") end if%>>Choose BA from list</option>
                    <option value="BAN" <%if sBaType = "BAN" then response.write(" selected ") end if%>>BA Norway</option>
                    <option value="FS" <%if sBaType = "FS" then response.write(" selected ") end if%>>BA F. Services</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>People selection: &nbsp;</b>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img src="images/eraser.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" title="Clear selection!" onclick="JavaScript:resetSelectElement(Form1.Selection);" />
        </a>
                <img src="images\Transparent.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="Selection" class="TdInput" style="width: 180px; height: 100px;" multiple>
                    <%
            sSql=_
                "select t.user_id, person_info_api.get_name(t.user_id) name "&_
                "from EDB_BA_EXCEL_LIST_TAB t "&_
                "where t.ba = '"&sBaType&"' "&_
                "order by 2"
            set rs=ConnOracle.Execute(sSql)
            Do while not rs.eof%>
                    <option value="<%=rs("user_id")%>" <%if instr(sSelection,rs("user_id"))>0 then response.write(" selected ") end if%>><%=rs("name")%></option>
                    <%
                rs.MoveNext
            loop%>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Additional selection:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="empno" value="<%=sEmpNo%>" class="TdInput" maxlength="40" style="width: 180px;" />

                <img style="cursor: pointer;" src="/PeoplePicker/Images/more4.png" border="0" width="13" height="13" title="Lookup employee..." onclick="javaScript: void (MainWindow = 
                    window.open('/PeoplePicker/indexEmpNo.asp?FormName=Form1&FieldName=empno&AddReplace=R', 'PeoplePicker', 'resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=580, height=300'))" />

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>Project ID:
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                <input type="text" class="tdinput" size="10" maxlength="10" name="projectid" value="<%=sProjectID%>" style="width: 180px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>Show output on: &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                <select name="output" class="TdInput" style="width: 180px">
                    <option value="" <%if sOutput = "" then response.write(" selected ") end if%>>Select from list</option>
                    <option value="Email" <%if sOutput = "Email" then response.write(" selected ") end if%>>Email</option>
                    <option value="Screen" <%if sOutput = "Screen" then response.write(" selected ") end if%>>Screen</option>
                    <option value="Both" <%if sOutput = "Both" then response.write(" selected ") end if%>>Both</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Run Script..." onclick="if ( confirm('Confirm that you want to create report for <%=request("batype")%>, ' + Form1.projectid.value + '!')) {Form1.Action.value = 'Save';}" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search..." name="send" class="button" onclick="Form1.Action.value = 'Search'" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is the code that where i'm trying to create to accomplish it, but currently not working..:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
msg = " ";
console.log(Form1.projectid.value);
if ( Form1.projectid.value =! null) 
   {
    msg = "Confirm that you want to create report for " + Form1.batype.value + " , " + Form1.projectid.value + "!";
    confirm(msg)
    }
else 
{
    msg = "Confirm that you want to create report for the project " + Form1.projectid.value + "!";
    confirm(msg) 
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
</script>
```

Any help on this?

Comment: well first of all looks like you are mixing js and jquery. and what are errors you getting in console?

Comment: you can write the html form?

Comment: Darsh: to tell you the truth, im not very skilled at this, so i have accually copy pasted most of the code. It is mainly written in classic asp. And when replacing the myFunction() in the button "Run Script.." i did not get anything, meaning the Confirm pop-up did not even appear... and no error messages....

Comment: hi.. is myFunction() written in a separate js file?

Comment: No, just added it inside the <body> tags...

Comment: can you do a check..  put myFunction in "Run script" and do a `console.log(Form1.projectid.value)`

Comment: @Shwrk thanks for the suggestion.. I added it, and see where the error was.. i was missing " } "... But now the Form1.projectid.value is returning the value TRUE once i submit the form... Not sure where it is coming from...?